# \newcommand in imsart package

Tags: pdftex, miktex, tex-core

I am currently using the `imsart` package provided by

http://www.e-publications.org/ims/support/ims-instructions.html

However, it seems the pdfLatex/Latex/pdfTex/pdfTexify compilers cannot read one single line like

```
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
```

since I want to replace the tedious `\mathbb{R}` to simple `\R`. I am using Windows with Ctex based on MikTeX (I guess). Does anyone have experience in this problem?

Comment: You need to give some clues, eg what did you do, what error message did you get etc. the line on its own is legal latex, although \mathbb is not defined by default so it will give an error if you use \R unless you define \mathbb eg via amsfonts package

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Did you add in your document `\usepackage{amssymb}` or `\usepackage{amsfonts}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please give more complete examples, but using

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yihui/stat-sci-cranvas/master/imsart.cls

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yihui/stat-sci-cranvas/master/my_imsart.sty

the following document

```
\documentclass{imsart}

\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}

\begin{document}
$\R $

\end{document}
```

produces the error message

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\R ->\mathbb 
             {R}
l.6 $\R
        $
?
```

showing the error is that `\mathbb` is not defined. Adding `amsfonts` package allows it to run without error

```
\documentclass{imsart}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}

\begin{document}
$\R $

\end{document}
```